# WPF C# SaveFileDialog - Reopen Dialog if filename exists in alternate folder

Tags: wpf, savefiledialog

I have a WPF project where I have a "Backup" folder that autosaves. If the user chooses a different name when they save the project, I check the Backup folder first and warn them if there's already a project with that name. If so, I want to reopen the SaveFileDialog and allow them to rename.

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml";
dlg.Filter = "xml documents (.xml)|*.xml|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
dlg.FileName = ProjectName;
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    string changedFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlg.FileName);
    if (changedFilename != CurrentProjectName)
    {
        if (ExistingProjectNames.Contains(changedFilename))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Project name " + changedFilename + " already exists. Continue?", "Existing Project Name", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                CurrentProjectName = changedFilename;
                WriteFile(dlg.FileName);
            }

            else
            {
            //go back to beginning and open dialog again so user can rename
            }
```

It seems pretty simple, but I can't think of the best way to do this. I've thought of recursion and switch statements, but it seems like I'm making it too complicated. Is there a more "standard" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is register for the `FileOk` event on the dialog before showing it. The event handler will be called when the user presses the Save button in the dialog, and you have the option of setting `e.Cancel = true` to prevent the dialog from closing and allow the user to make another choice.

Another option is to show the dialog in a `while` loop until whatever condition is satisfied, causing it to keep reopening until the user does what they need to do.

Comment: FileOk event sounds like exactly what I'm looking for; something to check the value between the time the user presses OK and the time the dialog closes. Thanks!